# Text over image does not work when browser resized

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, web

**Background**

I needed some basic text over image for my website.I have done so by first giving a transparent black box using rgb and rgba functions.Then placed text over it by declaring image as "relative" and text as "absolute".

**Problem**

When I resize the browser,the text runs out of image in downward direction.
It is shown in https://jsfiddle.net/Lheg26kw/
Here is html-

```
<div class="hero-container">
<div class="hero-image">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Old-Style_Balinese_Cat.png" width=100% height=80%>
<div class="hero-text">
    <p>This is text<br>
    <span>this is some more text for trial of this problem</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is **CSS**:

```
.hero-image{
position: relative;
width: 100%;

}
.hero-text p{ 
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding-top: 80px;
 color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
 }

.hero-text span{
font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Need**

I need the text to stay on image after resizing to minimum amount i.e. if website is accessed through a mobile.

Comment: Your padding-top for your paragraph is a fixed amount of pixels (80px). That's why your text is being pushed down. Make the padding-top a percentage (ie. 10%) to keep it relative to the image.

Comment: add a top 20 - 25% to the text and give your image a minimum width i.e 320px or you can have a look at flexbox and use this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone the content to another div below the hero and then hide the .`hero-text`

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {

  var $mobileContent = $('.mobile-content');
  var $bodyWidth = $('body').width();

  if ($bodyWidth < 620) {
    var $innerHero = $('.hero-text').html();
    $mobileContent.html($innerHero);
  } else {
    $mobileContent.empty();
  }

}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}

.hero-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.hero-text p {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.hero-text span {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.mobile-content {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
@media(max-width: 620px) {
  .hero-text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hero-container">
  <div class="hero-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/05/Old-Style_Balinese_Cat.png" width=100% height=80%>
    <div class="hero-text">
      <p>This is text
        <br>
        <span>this is some more text for trial of this problem</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobile-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put a minimum size on the image then eventually the text won't fit no matter what. But one thing I'd suggest is changing your `padding-top: 80px;` from a constant value of 80px to a percentage like `padding-top: 25%;`. This will help it scale better as the image changes in size.

Answer (score 0):

This will work: (replace your css with these)

```
  .hero-image{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;    
  }
  .hero-image img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
  }
  .hero-text{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  .hero-text p{ 
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
    width:100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin:0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bolder;
  }

  .hero-text span{
    font-weight: normal;
  }
```